# Formatted String and DateTime?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, wcf

I have a WCF class,

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Membership
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID;

        public DateTime? StartDate{ get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "StartDate")]
        public string StartDateString
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.StartDate.HasValue)
                    return this.StartDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                else
                    return null;
            }
            set
            {
                this.StartDate = Utils.ToNullableDateTime(this.StartDateString);
            }
        }

        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "EndDate")]
        public string EndDateString
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.EndDate.HasValue)
                    return this.EndDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                else
                    return null;
            }
            set
            {
                this.EndDate = Utils.ToNullableDateTime(this.EndDateString);
            }
        }


        public Membership() 
        {
                    //do something
        }
    }
}
```

It sends correct values when I populate this object in C# and send it to JavaScript, BUT it gives me StartDate, StartDateString, EndDate and EndDateString, when I call a post query in WCF method for it,

```
var memberships = [];
memberships.push({
    ID: id,
    StartDateString: $("#" + id + "governmentsddatepicker").val(),
    EndDateString: $("#" + id + "governmenteddatepicker").val()
});
```

IN debugger I am getting right values from jQuery selector, it's just in WCF method, I am getting null,

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: '{ "Memberships": ' + JSON.stringify(memberships) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
```

In WCF,

```
    public void UpdateMemberships(Membership[] memberships)
    {
        //do some work 
       // GETTING all dates here null
    }
```

Rest ID and other datamembers (I removed to short this question) work fine.

**Other then this bug above - I want**

I want to control the format way I am returning my DateTime to client but I also want to control the way I receiving DateTime from client and populate my dates string accordingly

**Edit**

This is what JS is posting after stringy function,

> JSON.stringify(memberships) =
>   "[{"ID":"53","StartDateString":"23/07/2015","EndDateString":"28/07/2015"}]"

Answer (score 0):

It can be a stupid answer, but why you use `''` after data : ?

You use :

```
 data: '{ "Memberships": ' + JSON.stringify(memberships) + '}',
```

But I think you have to use

```
data: { "Memberships":  JSON.stringify(memberships)},
```

Comment: Please see edit in my question, I suspect if there is anything wrong with data I am posting to WCF service :(, also in WCF I get all data members except this dateTime fields and there relevant strings

Comment: Sometimes javascript doesn't work very well. I don't understand why you use "plus" after json.stringify . Try to use this:
data: "{'data1':'" + value1+ "', 'data2':'" + value2"'}",